# Multiple count queries in the one my result table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, mytable which has a numeric column myint.

I wish to get the number of rows that are above 10, above 8 but below 10, above 5 but below 8 and present them in on result table as:

```
above 10 | above 8 below 10 | above 5 below 8
27       | 17               | 300
```

I can get them vertical using a `union all`. Must I use a join to get them horizontal?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    SUM (CASE WHEN myint > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'above 10',
    SUM (CASE WHEN myint BETWEEN 8 AND 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'above 8 below 10',
    SUM (CASE WHEN myint BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'above 5 below 8'
FROM mytable
```

Comment: whereas it's still not correct. above means greater to me. so the second line basically could be `= 9`

Comment: I think OP can put actual values himself base on his understanding of `above` and `below`

Answer (score 1):

Change `<` to `<=` or `>` to `>=` if you wante to include uper or lower bounds

```
select 
(select count(*) from myTable where myint > 10) as "above 10",
(select count(*) from myTable where myint > 8 and myint < 10) as "above 8 below 10",
(select count(*) from myTable where myint > 5 and myint <8) as "above 5 below 8"
from myTable
```

Comment: Can be horribly slow with much data

Comment: Always consider worst case, like you have no index on myint or anything. With your solution the table is scanned three times. Whereas with Jakub's solution it's only scanned one time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN myInt > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '>10',
SUM(CASE WHEN myInt > 8 AND myInt < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '(8-10)',
SUM(CASE WHEN myInt > 5 AND myInt < 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '(5-8)'
from    mytable
```

- Note that you are not returning where myInt = 8 as it is excluded from all selections.

This is probably the fastest way of doing it.